# How to persist state of Akka Graphs

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-persistence

I am using Akka Stream and Graphs and I would like to preserve the current state of a graph i.e. for a server reboot. Is there a way (and what would be the best practice) of preserving the state of graphs. If this makes a difference, I have also implemented some custom shapes and stages. There are plenty of examples for plain actors but nothing on streams or graphs.

Comment: well... that you can store the state how-ever and where-ever you want. As such there is no standard way of doing it. You will have to add some state persistence to every graph stage and make that graph-stage to build from that persisted state.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh but how would you save the state of such a flow: `Flow[E].sliding(win, 1).map(rows => rows.avg)`. I guess one has to hook into the materializer somehow. serializng the whole graph is also not an option since these are not serializeable

Comment: You can not. You will have to write your own custom graph stages.